# Can a single object in an array be exported?

Tags: export

Just wondering if a single object which is part of an array can be easily selected for export. I have tried in edit mode pressing the P key but can't work out how to quickly select every face in the object (I can hold down the shift key and LMB on each face but there are heaps of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid unexpected behaviours, it's better to duplicate the object (Shift D) and apply the array modifier.

Then in edit mode there are several ways of fast selecting, some of them:

B to box select, C to paint select, L to select all the area where the mouse is hovering, Ctrl L to select all the geometry linked to the selected area, H to hide every unwanted or occluding geometry, Ctrl I to invert the selection, vertex groups select/unselect buttons (if there are vertex groups), Alt left click to select loops, ....

When all the desired area is selected you can press P to separate it into a new object and delete the duplicate.